# How to apply/remove asp.net required validation for 3 different DIV based on condition?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ASPX UI page in which there are 3 different tabs which are getting submitted one by one

The three tabs are as follows:

tab 1- registration
tab 2- details
tab 3- contact Us

I am using single submit button to submit all 3 tabs (based on condition)

I want to disable validation for other fields in div 2 & 3, when i submit form in 1 div. i.e. in registration div when i click submit other 2 divs must not give validation error. & same while submitting other 2 divs.

```html
<div id=mainDiv>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="steps-lap">
   <li role="presentation" class="active" id="listOne" runat="server"><asp:HyperLink ID="tabOne" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#tab_one" data-toggle="tab">1: Basic Details</asp:HyperLink></li>
   <li role="presentation" id="listTwo" runat="server"><asp:HyperLink ID="tabTwo" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#tab_two" data-toggle="tab">2: Property Details</asp:HyperLink></li>
   <li role="presentation" id="listThree" runat="server"><asp:HyperLink ID="tabThree" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#tab_three" data-toggle="tab">3: Finish</asp:HyperLink></li>
 </ul>


<div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">

<!-- TAB-1 STARTS-->
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" role="tabpanel" id="tab_one" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
 <div id="registrationDetails">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="" TabIndex="1" onkeypress="return keyRestrictValidChars(event, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="rfv-error" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* required" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtFullName" ValidationGroup="DetailsGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

  <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="" TabIndex="1" onkeypress="return keyRestrictValidChars(event, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="rfv-error" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* required" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtFullName" ValidationGroup="DetailsGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                                    
 </div>
</div>
<!-- TAB-1 ENDS-->

<!-- TAB-2 STARTS-->
<div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="tab_two" aria-labelledby="dropdown2-tab">
   <div id="AllContent" runat="server" class="form-group" style="display:block;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtContact" runat="server" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="" TabIndex="1" onkeypress="return keyRestrictValidChars(event, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="rfv-error" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* required" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtContact" ValidationGroup="DetailsGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="" TabIndex="1" onkeypress="return keyRestrictValidChars(event, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="rfv-error" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* required" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="DetailsGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- TAB-2 ENDS-->

<!-- TAB-3 STARTS-->
<div class="tab-pane fade " role="tabpanel" id="tab_three" aria-labelledby="dropdown3-tab">
 <div id="CompletedContent">
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="" TabIndex="1" onkeypress="return keyRestrictValidChars(event, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="rfv-error" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* required" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="DetailsGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
</div>
<!-- TAB-3 ENDS -->


<div class="input-group">
  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Class="btn btn-default-color btn-sm" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="DetailsGroup"/>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

As shown in the code on page load 1st tab will be active when i submit fields in 1st tab will be saved, will move to 2nd tab, then fields in 2nd tab will be filled & submitted, 3rd tab will be active.

But what happening now is when i submit details of 1st tab, it gives  required field validation error because of textfields in other two divs.

Is there any way to handle such condition??

I have switch case in codebehind .cs file, based on which the action on submitted div will be performed.

Note : textbox fields mentioned are for classification purpose only!

Also can i restrict user to go back to previous tab once it is filled up.

i.e. when user fills data in the 1st tab it will go to 2nd tab, also 1st tab will be disabled, user cant go to 1st tab.

Any suggestion will be helpful. thanks!!

Comment: I would suggest  to use 3 different forms, Each tab as a form, so at a time only one form can be submitted.

Comment: @amitwadhwani in an aspx page we can have only 1 form tag!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ValidationGroup` attibute of the aspnet Validators for that.

```
<div id="tab1">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        ValidationGroup="tabgroup1" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Tab 1 required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button tab 1" ValidationGroup="tabgroup1" />
</div>

<div id="tab2">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
        ValidationGroup="tabgroup2" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Tab 2 required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button tab 2" ValidationGroup="tabgroup2" />
</div>

<div id="tab3">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"
        ValidationGroup="tabgroup3" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Tab 3 required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button tab 3" ValidationGroup="tabgroup3" />
</div>
```

Comment: please note that i am using the same button for submitting data of each & every tab. In code behind switch case is there to handle how button will execute operations for every other tab.

Comment: Then either use 3 different buttons or create a `CustomValidator` that can handle multiple tabs.