# How to keep two buttons for two different functions in an ASP.NET web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a website. Following screenshot are of my Login/Signup link page. When I'm clicking on Login button without giving any data, it is showing me an ALERT. Its OK. But the problem is that, when I'm pressing Register button to go to Signup/Registration page, at that time "Text Boxes" is also showing me this validation. That's why I'm unable to go to Signup/Registration page.

```html
<table id="Table2" runat="server" align="center" style="margin-top:15px; width:72%; height:170px">
                              <tr style="text-align:center; width:80%; height:8px;">
                                  <td style="font-size:medium; font-family:Courier New; font-weight:bold ;color:#000000; text-align:left ; width:20%; height:8px;">Mobile No</td>
                                  <td style=" width:40%;height:8px"><input type="number" id="mobnum"  runat="server" style="width:70%; height:23px" required="required" /></td>
                                 

                              </tr>
                              <tr style="text-align:center; width:80%; height:8px">
                                  <td style="font-size:medium; font-family:Courier New; font-weight:bold ;color:#000000; text-align:left ; width:30%; height:8px">Password</td>
                                  <td style="width:50%; height:8px"><asp:TextBox id="TextBox8" runat="server" style="width:70%; height:23px;" TextMode="Password" re ></asp:TextBox></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="text-align:center; width:80%; height:29px">
                                  <td style="width:30%; height:29px"></td>
                                  <td style="width:50%; height:29px"><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="IsValid"  height="30px" width="100px" BackColor="#006400" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="White" Text="Login" Font-Bold="true" /></td>
                              </tr>
                          </table>
                          
                          <table id="Table4" runat="server" align="center" style="margin-top:15px; width: 72%; height:170px">
                              <tr style="text-align:center; width:100%; height:8px;">
                                  <td style="width:100%; height:10px; text-align:center"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Signup.aspx" CausesValidation="false" height="30px" width="100px" BackColor="#006400" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="White" Text="Register" Font-Bold="true" OnClick="Button1_Click" /></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="text-align:center; width:80%; height:22px;">
                                  <td style="width:100%; height:22px"></td>
                              </tr>
                          </table>
```

Comment: post some code, please

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543294/how-to-apply-remove-asp-net-required-validation-for-3-different-div-based-on-con

Comment: Didn't see the _Following screenshot_

Answer (score 0):

You need to *group* those validations per page (or) based on different actions. In essence you should look for [Specifying Validation Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx)

Comment: Sounds like he's only got one validation group on the page for login and that he's trying to redirect to the registration page when he clicks on registration.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the attribute CausesValidation="false" to your Register button.

Like this

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="OnClick" CausesValidation="false"/>
```

That will skip any validation on your page and allow you to go to your registration page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can handle this situation;
1. In regester/signup button set CauseValidation to false.

2. Set ValidationGroup property of Login button and give same ValidationGroup name to all validators.